# Insert data from database into jtextfield

Tags: java, database, ms-access, insert, textfield

I want to insert data from my Microsoft Access database into a textfield.

I have already made a login system. I only want to insert the data into a textfield from the account that's logged in. With data I mean first name, last name etc.

What's the best way to do this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this library to read a value from ms access file: http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/ and after put it into textfield.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a sql connection to the Access database using a [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) driver for MS Access.

You then need to execute a SQL command against that Access database to retrieve the data you wish to display.  This data will be returned as a SQL [ResultSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) object.

Have you worked with databases before?  If not, there is perhaps some reading you need to do on the subject.  [Check this google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=JDBC%20tutorial%20with%20MS%20access)

Comment: I can login with data (username and password) from my database. Forgot to say I already made the connection. I'll try to find something about the SQL command you're talking about but I don't really know where to look..

Answer (score 0):

Well, you read the data from the database using JDBC or some more highlevel object mapper like Hibernate or Eclipselink and map the returned data to your textfields.

Basically you need several steps:

- a query to get the data for the logged in account
- execute that query on the database using JDBC or something more highlevel
- put the returned result into your textfields

If you want to update the data as well, you'd need to

- extract the data from your textfields
- create an update query and associate the data with it
- execute the update query

Some things to take into account:

- do you need some lock mechanism to prevent lost updates/dirty reads?
- do you want to validate the data before persisting it?

Comment: I've made a DbObject with the connection to my database in it and I've made the frame with the textfields where I want to show the data in. 

The first three steps are quite difficult but that's what I need. What I understand is I need the query to read data and put the data in the textfields. Can you explain it more clearly for me?

Comment: @Ard Well, if you already have a `DbObject` and are able to read the data from the database, all you have to do is get the data from that `DbObject` and put it into the textfield (IIRC the method is `setText(...)`). If you don't have the `DbObject` yet, read up on how you read data from a databse using JDBC then use a query to read the data and fill the data into your `DbObjec` first.

Comment: I think the problem is I don't know what query to use. I worked with a query before but that was about show the whole database in a table. Now I just want to show the data from the account that's logged in. I already have the DbObject and the connection works because I can login with username and password (stored in database).

Comment: @Ard well the query would be something like `SELECT * FROM account WHERE username='someusername'`. Of course table and column names depend on your database layout and 'someusername' is a placeholder. Basically you just get the one row that matches the given conditions. Then extract the indivudal fields from the resultset that represents that row. Note that this assumes accounts are identified by a unique username. For more information you should look into SQL and how to write those queries.